# Fatal error: Call to undefined function logged in

Tags: php, database, authentication

I have this error in my code:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function com_is_logged() in
```

The function is:

```
// Check if user is logged
function com_is_logged()
{
    //Here you need to check if the user is logged into your website and then return TRUE or FALSE
    if (isset($_SESSION[sforum_.'sforum_logged_in']))
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

These are the session variable:

```
$_SESSION[sforum_.'sforum_logged_in']
```

Any help will be thanked

Comment: Where do you call the function?  Is it out of the function scope?

Comment: You probably forgot to include the file that contains the function

Comment: @john Conde  it as the require_once('functions.php'); its there, thank you.

Comment: @Fred -ii the curly ones it not in the code, it as the '

Comment: Then you should post your actual code.

Answer (score 0):

"Undefined function" means that the function doesn't exist. You showed us the function, but that doesn't help. What is happening is that your code is trying to call the function somewhere and the function hasn't been created yet.

This probably means that you didn't include the right file or have a syntax error. Finding the place where you call the function and see if the function has been included. If the function has been included or is on the same file, check that all of your code is correct and you aren't missing and semicolons or closing brackets.

Comment: The line that gives the error is :<?php if ( !com_is_logged() ) : ?>

Comment: But where is that line in relation to the code above? Is it in the same file? If it isn't in the same file, are you sure you are including the file with the function in it correctly?

Comment: it as the require_once('functions.php');

Comment: we'll need your actual code and file structure to figure it out, you just aren't connecting them right